# Fixing a push to the wrong branch

Tags: mercurial

I committed and pushed some changes to the wrong branch. I found a way to fix it, but it seems overly complicated. Is this really the easiest way?

1. on the branch that you made your changes, type `hg parent`
2. run `hg diff -r <parent> -r <with_changes> > patch.diff`
3. `hg up <proper_branch>`
4. `hg import --no-commit patch.diff`
5. `hg ci -m 'committing changes to proper branch'`
6. `hg up <bad_branch>`
7. `hg parent` to find previous changeset on this branch that is good
8. `hg ci --close-branch -m 'closing bad branch'`
9. `hg up <last_good_changeset>`
10. add a space or other minor change
11. `hg ci -m 'making tip'`
12. `hg push`

Something to that effect anyway. I did it in a slightly different order; I made the good changeset the tip again, and had to do a force commit because it creates a new head, then had to run

```
hg heads `hg branch`
```

To find the bad branch again, then close it. Now it still shows the bad changeset as the "tip" because I closed it *after* I "re-tipped" the good branch, but when updating to that branch, I guess it takes the most recent non-closed head?

Seems like quite a ridiculous process to fix such a simple mistake.

Is there any easier way to do this? Why not?

Comment: I'm not an expert in mercurial, but my thinking is that you should leave it complicated. If it's painful to undo, maybe it'll deter you from doing it again :)

Comment: @JoelEtherton You can't deter accidents.

Comment: @Joe Zeng: Accidents happen when people are inattentive. You can deter inattentiveness. Ergo, you can deter accidents.

Comment: @JoelEtherton Accidents also happen when people are attentive. Making the consequences hard to fix is not a good deterrent from doing something when you don't even know you're doing it. You can never be attentive enough that accidents *never* happen.

Comment: @Joe Zeng: You must have missed the smiley at the end of my first comment indicating it's tongue in cheek. Go away.

Comment: Mecurial (like other vcs) knows the `revert` command too.

Comment: @JoelEtherton I've seen enough people use that smiley face to mask a real criticism that I can't tell. Sorry for misunderstanding you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did find a cleaner solution. You don't need to "touch" the branch to bring it back to tip, nor close off the bad branch.

Instead, just up to the bad branch, `hg revert -r <last_good_commit> -a` then recommit.

Since you're upping to the tip of the bad branch it doesn't create a new head, and then your reverted changes get pushed to the tip instead.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any easier way to do this?

Yes. `hg help rebase`: rebase changeset to the new correct parent and push

**PS**: you have to enable Rebase extension before using command

Comment: The issue with this is it assumes that the two branches are identical aside from the changes you just made. Usually there's a few other changes I need to keep, so really, I need a diff of the changes I made so that it can be applied to the proper branch.

Answer (score 0):

`hg rollback` will rollback the LAST transaction if you have not pushed.  If you've committed or pushed work after the transaction you want to make go away, it will not work.  `hg help rollback` for details.

Comment: First sentence...I said it's already pushed ;)

Comment: this is not a good idea. You will lose your work using this.

Comment: Sorry I missed the push note.

You will not lose any work, you will rollback your work directory to what it looked like before the commit.  You can then make any changes you want and commit again.